# Python не видит мои модули в импортах при запуске скрипта из терминала

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Есть проект на питоне, там есть свое окружение.

Когда запускаю проект в PyCharm всё хорошо запускается.

Когда запускаю проект в терминале, зайдя предварительно в окружение, пишет такого модуля(только в отношении моих модулей)

Все `__init__.py` на месте, не понимаю в чем дело(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там по структуре ничего хитрого, вот примерно так

```
ROOT
├── helpers
│   ├── my_module_1.py
│   ├── my_module_2.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
├── tests
│   ├── test1.py ("from helpers.my_module_1 import *")
│   ├── test2.py
│   └── ....
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скрины это конечно хорошо но толку мало ) Вы лучше приложите структуру проекта. Что где лежит и как импортируется?

Comment: @Kers 
Добавил к основному описанию

Comment: А не пробовали запускать через `python -m pytest`?

Comment: @AndyPavlov Не чего себе, а сработало. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить текущую директорию в `PYTHONPATH`

На линуксе делается так:

```bsh
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)
```

После этого должно заработать.

На винде вот так (не проверял):

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
```

Comment: Я что то такое нагугливал, когда пытался разобраться сам.
Вообще не понимаю как это должно работать, "текущая директория" это директория проекта что ли, та что в prompt string. Добавил на винде, ничего не поменялось( . Добавил скрин к основному описанию. Этот способ точно должен работать в виртуальном окружении?